# pod service not accessible from host

Tags: docker, kubernetes, tcp, connection

As the title says, I am unable to use a service a certain *pod* is providing.
The *pod* is serving a **java restApi** service at **TCP port 2040**, that I should be able to access with some specific curl commands.

Some data from **kubectl describe pod** :

> Status:         Running
> IP:             172.17.0.32
> Node:           minikube/13*.20*.13*.14 (I obfuscated my real IP here)
> Container ID:   docker://b5b16bd7926ce65d4a57212f60c87ea72e161f534a0e1d6925c508dd89ab202e
> Ports:          9899/TCP, 1272/TCP, 2040/TCP, 9500/TCP, 9501/TCP, 9502/TCP, 9503/TCP, 9504/TCP
> Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP

(is this correct ?)

I am confused by the fact that :

A) I am perfectly able to issue curl commands on the shell inside the docker container (b5b16bd7926ce65...)

B) The tcp connection from my host to the service the pod is providing is successful :

> user@host$ nc -zv 172.17.0.32 2040
> Connection to 172.17.0.32 2040 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

C) any curl command (from the host) towards *172.17.0.32:2040* fails with :
504 Gateway Timeout: remote server did not respond to the proxy

The host is running **Ubuntu 18.04LTS**.
I am behind a *corporate proxy*, but as this is all done on my local machine, I don't think that could be an issue.

What could be responsible for this behavior?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here was the proxy, adding  --noproxy "*"  to the curl command made it work from the host.

I however do not understand why this is required, I am hosting everything my self?

Comment: I think `curl` is reading the proxy address from your `http_proxy` variable on your host machine.